# iPhone code signing -- why would developer build complain about lack of distribution certificate?

Tags: iphone, code-signing

Here is the error I am getting.  This is preventing me from testing the **developer** build of my app on my iPad device.  The "failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)" line grabs my attention, but I have no idea what it means.

```
Validate /Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-fduucejdaajqvxekndurxjggarcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.app
cd /Users/william/Documents/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-fduucejdaajqvxekndurxjggarcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.app

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-fduucejdaajqvxekndurxjggarcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.app/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
/Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-fduucejdaajqvxekndurxjggarcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.app: valid on disk
/Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-fduucejdaajqvxekndurxjggarcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: failed to execute codesign(1)
 - (null)
```

I am doing a debug build, signing as my developer identity.  Here is the output of codesign in the terminal:

```
Williams-iMac:Debug-iphoneos william$ codesign -dvvv GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.app
Executable=/Users/william/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe-fduucejdaajqvxekndurxjggarcu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe.app/GraphingCalculatorDeluxe
Identifier=com.jockusch.calculator
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (armv7)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=10772 flags=0x0(none) hashes=530+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=96b088a0cd93ff9b5adc9552bbc29e4cef247356
Signature size=4338
Authority=iPhone Developer: William Jockusch (B86JCKGV32)
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=Jul 10, 2012 8:08:35 PM
Info.plist entries=30
Sealed Resources rules=3 files=564
Internal requirements count=1 size=292
Williams-iMac:Debug-iphoneos william$
```

EDIT: I'm telling Xcode to use my developer profile.  See the screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: Libraries don't have to be signed.

Comment: Try setting all of your profiles to development. Then just change back to distribution when you're ready to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was apparently related to Xcode mixing up two different developer accounts.

I develop both for myself and as a team with someone else.  I had recently submitted an app for the team.  As a result, the portion of Xcode that logs in to iTunes Connect to distribute apps was set to that account.

When I compiled this app, even though all the settings appear to be pointing to stuff on my own account, some part of the team information was apparently confusing some aspect of it.

The reason I believe this is that the problem went away after I did the following:

1. Go to the organizer.
2. Navigate to an archive of the app.
3. Click the "distribute" button.
4. Sign in to iTunes connect as myself
5. I then got a message saying that no suitable application records were found.
6. Build again, problem recurred.
7. quite Xcode and delete my build folder.
8. Restart Xcode
9. Repeat steps 1-5.
10. Build again.  It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you've set the **Code Signing**'s name (your project target -> Build Settings -> Code Signing) correctly:

[image]